# How to get Facebook friend's Anniversary date using graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How to get facebook friend's anniversary date using grapg api.I searced a lot in developer.facebook.com graph api.but there is no such options to get that.can anybody help me plz ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **marriage anniversary**-

There's no such api that can fetch this for you.

---

If you mean **birthday anniversary**-

You can fetch with -

```
/ID?fields=birthday
```

with permission: `user_birthday`